# DataTable Is Empty

Tags: c#, datatable, dataadapter

I am attempting to run a stored procedure and add the results to a data table.  My stored procedure executes as it should, bc if I query the table the results are stored in from SSMS - the accurate results are there.  However, my code below will produce `numberofrecords = 0` everytime!

What did I set-up incorrectly in this syntax below?

```
using (conn = new SqlConnection(SQLConn))
{
using (cmd = new SqlCommand(storedprocname, conn))
{
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("d1", SqlDbType.Date, 100);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("d2", SqlDbType.Date, 100);
  cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = cboNames.Text.ToString();
  cmd.Parameters["d1"].Value = dtpd1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
  cmd.Parameters["d2"].Value = dtpd2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dolla", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
  cmd.Parameters["@Dolla"].Value = cboDolla.Text.ToString();

  using (da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
  {
    da.Fill(dt);
  }

  int numberOfRecords = 0;
  numberOfRecords = dt.Select().Length;
  MessageBox.Show(numberOfRecords.ToString());
}
```

And these are my class variable declarations:

```
    public static SqlCommand cmd;
    public static SqlDataAdapter da;
    public static DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    public static DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

**EDIT**
And this is my stored proc which produces roughly 32 rows

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[TestParamQuery]
(
  @Name varchar(max)
  ,@d1 varchar(100)
  ,@d2 varchar(100)
  ,@dolla varchar(500)
)
As

Select 
EmployeeName
,EmployeeNumber
,CAST(hiredate As Date) [hire date]
,saleamount
FROM [TestDB].[dbo].[SalesFigs]
WHERE employeename = @Name
AND hiredate between @d1 AND @d2
AND saleamount >= @dolla
```

**EDIT 2**
This is how I execute the stored procedure to ensure it is returning the results I want from directly inside SSMS

```
USE [TestDB]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[TestParamQuery]
        @Name = N'Sam Wise',
        @d1 = N'03/01/2016',
        @d2 = N'01/30/2016',
        @Dolla = N'1000'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Comment: It would be helpful to show SP code also.

Comment: I would avoid declaring those class variables, and instead declare them inside your function, and output the `DataTable` as the function return value.

Comment: @JamesFaix - I declared them as class variables as I use them in multiple methods, so instead of declaring multiple times in multiple methods I just use them as class variables.  For example, I have one method that runs a SQL stored proc that just writes data to a SQL table.  Then I have a seperate method (the one above) that runs a SQL stored procedure that returns data (and I try to write to a datatable).  Is that still not a good idea to use class variables?

Comment: @JamesFaix - output DataTable as the function return value.  Write C# like so?  public DataTable ParamStoredProc(string procedurename)  -- then at the end use return dt;?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan - my stored proc runs as expected.  It runs a create table statement, then inserts data into that table.  If I query the table from SSMS valid and expected results exist, but when I run my syntax - which is a select statement from the table created in the proc the data table is empty.

Comment: Generally I would keep the scope of every variable as small as possible.  For these variables, you create a new instance every time you run the method (and probably your other methods), so each use of the variables is unrelated to the other uses.  Because of this, I would hide each variable inside the methods in which they are being used.  You may save a few lines of code the way you are doing it, but you are not avoiding any overhead, as you still have to initialize a new instance for each variable each time.  There is also the possibility of old data getting into new method invocations.

Comment: @JamesFaix - valid point, thank you for pointing that out to my noobish self.  Should I then declare the variables as private inside the method to guarantee they are kept in the method only?

Comment: @MichaelMormon Inside a method, there are no access modifiers.  Everything declared only exists inside that method.  It's more private than `private`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, SqlCommand does not have an easy method or property for converting the command to a string, with all parameters and values included.  I have used a method like this in the past to make debugging commands easier:

```
public static string PrintCommand(this SqlCommand command){
    if (command == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("command");

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine(command.CommandText); 
    foreach (var p in command.Parameters){
        sb.AppendLine("\t" + p.ParameterName + ": " + p.Value); 
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

It should output a string like this:

```
"dbo.MyCommandName
    @Name: myNameParameterValue
    d1: 01/01/2016
    d2: 02/02/2016
    @Dolla: myDollaValue"
```

You can then invoke it like this, and check the value in a step-thru debugger.

```
using (conn = new SqlConnection(SQLConn))
using (cmd = new SqlCommand(storedprocname, conn)) {
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("d1", SqlDbType.Date, 100);
  cmd.Parameters.Add("d2", SqlDbType.Date, 100);
  cmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value = cboNames.Text.ToString();
  cmd.Parameters["d1"].Value = dtpd1.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
  cmd.Parameters["d2"].Value = dtpd2.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
  cmd.Parameters.Add("@Dolla", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100);
  cmd.Parameters["@Dolla"].Value = cboDolla.Text.ToString();

  //Get a text representation here:
  var text = cmd.PrintCommand();

  //Put a breakpoint here to check the value:
  using (da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
  {
    da.Fill(dt);
  }

  int numberOfRecords = 0;
  numberOfRecords = dt.Select().Length;
  MessageBox.Show(numberOfRecords.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you cannot get values. But anyway please try this approach:

```
using (conn = new SqlConnection(SQLConn))
using (cmd = new SqlCommand(storedprocname, conn))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", cboNames.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d1", dtpd1.Value.ToShortDateString();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d2", dtpd2.Value.ToShortDateString();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Dolla", cboDolla.Text);

    using (da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
    }

    var numberOfRecords = dt.Rows.Count;
    MessageBox.Show(numberOfRecords);
}
```

Comment: same result as above numberOfRecords = 0

Comment: Are you sure that same parameters return data when you run with SSMS?
It seems that empty result is correct result. Could you try to change values you supply to stored procedure?

Comment: I have altered the variables numerous times.  I have stepped through my code, and in the VS "Autos" window, copy/paste the value being passed in the variable and run it directly in SSMS and I get results returned...

Comment: when you run in SSMS do you execute stored procedure or just run the query inside of it?

Comment: the code is correct. so problem is not in the c# code and not in proc. 
probably wrong database